# Can a USB to parallel port adapter recognize a "high" pin?

Tags: usb, parallel-processing

I’m building a custom “robotish” machine that has 8 switches I need to interface with a laptop. The only input to the laptop is via USB.

Here’s my idea:

When the switch is closed, it sends a 5v signal to one of the input pins on a parallel to USB adapter. This adapter translates this to a USB signal and sends it to the computer, which will be listening for it.

Here’s my question(s):

Will this even work? Will the USB adapter be able to tell the computer that pin 8 (or whatever) on the parallel port side of the adapter is high?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If pin8 is one of the data pins then yes (assuming the adapter supports bi-directional)

A lot of usb-serial/parralel adapters are very poorly made and have very very bad drivers so you might need to find one that somebody else has used.

Comment: @MD Take a look at some of the robotic and uC sites (Arduino, PIC) there may be PIC versions of a USB to generic I/O pins that are better. If you aren't $$$ limited then all the digital control/interface people make them.